# How to invoke Eclipse RCP perspective ( Java Class method) from JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, java, html, eclipse-rcp

I would like to invoke or open Perspective(or Views) from JavaScript function.

I have an Eclipse RCP application, where I have embedded My HTML page. On button click from HTML page, i would like to open Eclipse RCP perspective or View.

I have tried as shown below from javascript function

```
function populateGeometryData(){
alert('Inside populateGeometryData() function !!!!!');
var geoMetryDataClass = Java.type("com.test.app.ui.view.PageView");
geoMetryDataClass.populateGemetryData("TestVal");
}
```

Where PageView is one of my perspective. But I got " Uncaught ReferenceError: Java is not defined" .
 I think, this error is because of Chrome no longer supports NPAPI (technology required for Java applets). So, is there any other ways to invoke Java class method from JavaScript?

Below is how, I am launching my HTML page from Eclipse RCP code.

```
   @Override
   public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

    String user = ExecuteRestService.getLoggedInUser();
    System.out.println("Login User "+user);


    String html = "/Pages/index.html";
    Bundle appBundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass());
    if(appBundle == null) {
        System.out.println("bundle  is null");
        return;
    }

    URL url = FileLocator.find(appBundle, new Path(html), null);

    try {
        url = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block@*
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Browser  browser = new Browser(parent, SWT.None);
    String urlVal = url.toString()+"?LoginUser="+user;
    browser.setUrl(urlVal);

}
```

I am looking some suggestions to call Java Class Method or to Invoke Eclipse RCP perspective from JavaScript function. 
Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

As **Greg** suggested in comments section, using "**BrowserFunction**" we can call Java class method in Eclipse RCP from javascript if you are using SWT browser to launch your HTML page.

```
new BrowserFunction(browser, "populateGeometricData")
    {
        @Override
        public Object function(Object[] objects)
        {

            if(objects.length == 0) {
                System.out.println(" array is zero");
            }else {
                System.out.println("Call from Javascript" 
                         + objects.length);
                System.out.println("Request Id "+ objects[0]);
            }


            return null;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Is the HTML running in the SWT Browser in the RCP or is it in a normal Browser?

Comment: Hello Greg, HTML is running in the SWT Browser in the RCP.

Comment: Then use `BrowserFunction` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44236878/2670892)

Comment: Greg, I used BrowserFunction and what i observed is, it invokes the java class method but code present inside my javascript function not called not even alert. along with invocation of javamethod from javascript function, i need to pass parameters as well . And I want to use those parameters value in my java method. will this possible?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you are saying. BrowserFunction is used to call a Java method from Javascript code in the browser. The [blog](http://blog.vogella.com/2009/12/21/javascript-swt/) linked in the answer explains in detail.

Comment: Thank you greg. It is working fine now.